# Get column names from a variable using json

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I have a variable that contain all the subject names that are the column names of a table.Now i got all column names in a variable.Use this variable name in select statement.

**Ajax**

```
success:function(result) { 
    console.log(result); 

    var tab = '';
   for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
                tab += "<div class='col-xs-12 mrgntTB3'>  <div class='row'>";
                tab += "<div class='col-xs-2 blk-ht1'><span class='tbRrptsstdNames'>" + result[i]["student_name"]+ "</span></div>";
                tab +=" <div class='col-ds-1'><span class='badge scrore scrore-pt bg-aqua'>"+ result[i]["english"]+"</span></div>";
                tab +="</div></div><div class='clearfix'></div>"
            }   
            $("#subjectNames").append(tab);  
    $("#subjectNames").append(tab);
 }
```

How can i take each subject names in ajax success like student name

Comment: try like this `result[i].student_name`

Comment: i got this..but i need subject names.All subjects are in a variable.How to take each subject name inside the for loop

Comment: you can try this 
Define array above loop `var arr = new Array();`  or `var arr = [];`
and inside loop `arr.push(result[i].student_name);`

Comment: So basically you want to get each one `english`,`hindi`,`maths` seperate from `english,hindi,maths`?

Comment: yes.I want each one seperately..Now all subject names are in a variable

Comment: @rose That means `result[i].student_name`  is something like `english,hindi,maths`, right?

Comment: What JSON are you receiving from your web service?

Comment: i'm not add  that..result[i].student_name this shows the student name that already got.Subject names contain in $subj_names.Can i use like .result[i].$subj_names

Comment: @Rose can you add a sample `json` from server?

Comment: Sure.I think ur answer is informative.can u edit that

Comment: @Rose `$subj_names` is a php variable, right?

Comment: yes..that variable is passed to my model..look this $this->db->select('student_name,'.$subj_names.'')

Comment: @Rose If you are able to access that variable in the place where you write your **js**, then you can create a variable `nameList = '<?php echo $simple; ?>'; nameArray = nameList.split(',');` then use that variable like I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102559/discussion-between-rose-and-rejith-r-krishnan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split and loop them like the following.

```
var tab = '';
var nameArray = [];
var keys = []; 
for(var k in result[0]) {
    keys.push(k);
}
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
    tab += "<div class='col-xs-12 mrgntTB3'>  <div class='row'>";
    tab += "<div class='col-xs-2 blk-ht1'>";
    tab += "<span class='tbRrptsstdNames'>" + result[i]["student_name"] + "</span><div>"
    for(j = 1; j < keys.length; j++){
        tab += "<div class='col-xs-2 blk-ht1'>";
        tab += "<span class='tbRrptsstdNames'>" + result[i][keys[j]] + "</span><div>"
    } 
    tab += "</div></div><div class='clearfix'></div> ";
}
```

Comment: @Rose take a look at this, some improvements might be needed,

Comment: u ther..i'm confused..can u help me ?

Comment: @rose you can always add a new good question. In that case you'll get better response.

Comment: @Rose let me know when you add the question.

Comment: i have doubt.can u plz help me

Comment: @robins I didn't get your question.

Comment: ok..In the for loop..data is getting the limit i<result.length..In my case i want to limit the data.

Comment: In a class 20 students are there.the marks of a particular subject taken as json object.In the first row shows six students then the next six is another row

Comment: In the console i got the data like this Ann:8
Saran:9.5
Dann:7..the stud name and mark

Comment: @robins If you can make some kind of jsfiddle demo, I might be able to help.